# How do I deploy many MSDeploy publish profiles in a single MSBuild command?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a project that I need to deploy with a couple of different configurations (specifically, deploying the same package to 2 different IIS applications). I have set up 2 Publish Profiles, and each creates a package when invoked individually. I'd like to create both packages with a single command.

I've tried commands like this, but they tend to simply ignore the second profile:

```
msbuild MyWebProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=True "/p:PublishProfile=FirstProfile;PublishProfile=SecondProfile"
```

Is there a way that I can use a single command to deploy both profiles?

Comment: I provided a solution to this issue in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434142/is-there-a-way-to-create-more-than-one-deployment-with-msbuild-on-a-single-build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't strictly what you are asking for, but have you considered building once and deploying twice?

To achieve this through msbuild, you could create an msbuild project which calls msdeploy.

**Build (Create Package)**

```
msbuild MyWebProject.csproj
    /p:DeployTarget=Package
    /p:PackageLocation=MyWebProject.zip
    /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
```

**Deploy Package Twice**

```
msdeploy.exe 
    -verb:sync 
    -source:Package=MyWebProject.Zip 
    -destination:auto:ComputerName="my.server1.com"
    -declareParamFile:Params1.xml

msdeploy.exe 
    -verb:sync 
    -source:Package=MyWebProject.Zip 
    -destination:auto:ComputerName="my.server2.com"
    -declareParamFile:Params2.xml
```

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing, since all I actually wanted to vary was the IIS name of the deployed app. For one install I used the IIS application name that was specified in the publish profile, and for the other I overrode that value in the command line as you suggested.